# Bash find folder in least deep subfolder

Tags: bash, find, subdirectory

I have this script for easy moving into folders.
My problem is, that if I search for `tests` but this folder is within my current folder and a subfolder, if the subfolder is searched first, it moves into the tests in the subfolder. But it should always move into the "lowest" match from the subfolder structure. Any ideas?

```
function f {
  if [[ -d $(find . -name $1 -type d) ]]; then
    cd $(find . -name $1 -type d)
  else
    cd $(find ~ -name $1 -type d)
  fi
}
```

Comment: Your title says `least deep`, your question says `lowest`?

Comment: Notice that "-type d" searches for directories, and "-type f" searches for files, but there is no option to search for "folders"...because they're called "directories"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear to me. Are just looking for something like

```
cd "$(find . -depth -type d -name "$1" -print -quit)"
```

Which will traverse the directory in dfs order and `cd` into the first matching `$1` it finds.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script:

```
cd $(for each in `find . -name $1 -type d`
do
   cnt=`echo $each | sed 's:[^/]::g' | awk '{print length}'`
   echo "$cnt $each"
done | sort -g | awk '{print $2}' | head -1)
```

- `find` inside for loop finds all directories with name $1
- `cnt` variable counts the no. of "/" in the paths.
- `sort -g` sorts the output based on `cnt` variable.
- `head -1` returns the first item in the sorted list which would be the "lowest" match.

Comment: Note, this will fail if filenames have whitespace.